# Unity: UI sliders moves strangely

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, slider

I have a slider in my canvas that doesn't work well. I can pick it and make it move, but when I release it, it continues to move, in a strange way, and the other sliders in my canvas start moving too. I'm using default unedited sliders, and my canvas is in World Space mode. Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you have any script attached to those sliders?

Comment: this doesn't really sound like the default behaviour ;) Are you sure there are no ther scripts changing values in those sliders?

Comment: They are default sliders, no scripts attached. I tried to remove them a place new ones, same thing :/

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this for a long time, and realized the problem was in the `Event System`'s `Standard Input Module` settings.

Horizontal and Vertical axes were set to `"MouseX"` and `"MouseY"`, respectively. Setting those back to `"Horizontal"` and `"Vertical"` fixed the odd issue where UI elements were receiving states as if there was another cursor moving over them.

Comment: Not sure why those values were changed in the first place - maybe those were the defaults at some point, or some plugin changed them...